# Kernel 4.1.18 doesn't support aes-xts-plain64

Tags: linux, kernel-modules, luks

My root partition is under a luks crypt and when I type in my password it tells me to make sure my kernel supports `aes-xts-plain64` and to check syslog for more info. Obviously I can't check syslog because my root partition isn't even mounted yet. This is my config https://drive.google.com/open?id=0BzW0t4K6XI4gQTh0c1lSSjEzQmc. I've tried setting `CRYPTO_XTS=y`, `CRYPTO_AES_NI_INTEL=y`, and `CRYPTO_AES_X86_64=y` but even with them built directly into the kernel I still have no luck. The kernel is 4.1.18 from kernel.org and I'm running Debian 8 Jessie.

Comment: Bug report: https://bugzilla.kernel.org/show_bug.cgi?id=112631

Comment: @jasonwryan you have no idea how long I spent looking for a solution and never stumbled on that bug report. Thanks for the info though.

Comment: We saw a few people experience this on the Arch boards earlier this week: you are not alone :) This ML thread has more detail about the bad commit https://www.spinics.net/lists/stable/msg120346.html